# .NET WireMock reject PostAsJsonAsync serialization

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, wiremock, wiremock.net

I have a WireMock API setup for testing purposes. First, I was using the short way to make a REST call to my WireMock endpoint:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("resorce/someRoute", obj);
```

This simply didn't work and I always got a "Not Found" response. After a lot of debugging without finding any issues regarding my REST calls and my WireMock setup, I tried the verbose way of doing the same functionality:

```
var json = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj),
    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("resorce/someRoute", json);
```

This time it worked! According to my information, both do the *same thing*.

What is the problem here? Is it a WireMock thing or `PostAsJsonAsync` may lead to different behaviour?

Here is a [short code example](https://gist.github.com/mnajj/194871c7fc193bd72fd58ed48af81798)

Comment: Do you have a [mre] you can share?

Comment: Hi Guru. Post updated with ex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostAsJsonAsync` uses `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` for serializer options which will result in Camel case property names in the JSON while `JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj)` will use default ones resulting in Pascal case (matching property names). There are multiple ways to handle that. For example changing the settings for `PostAsJsonAsync`:

```cs
var response = await httpCLient.PostAsJsonAsync("/hello-world", obj, new JsonSerializerOptions());
```

Or using the Camel case for the object:

```cs
_server.Given(
    Request.Create()
        .WithPath("/hello-world")
        .UsingPost()
        .WithBodyAsJson(new { command = "Say hello"} ))
```

Comment: For more complex objects you know the rest. Pass the custom serialized JSON content to WithBody() instead.

.WithBody(JsonSerializer.Serialize(complexObj,
new JsonSerializerOptions
{
  PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
}))